# SQL count involving multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables.`University` and `UniversityType`.Structure looks like this.
For University

```
    universityId universityName universityTypeId universityTypeName
        1            xyz              1                UGC
        2            abc              1                UGC
        3            lmn              2                NCT
        4            pqr              3                AICT
```

For `UniversityType`

```
    universityTypeId  universityTypeName
          1                UGC
          2                NCT
          3                AICT
```

The `UniversityType` table is fixed.Now I want to get the count of universityType that is UGC=2, AICT=1, NCT=1.Now I am writing something like this

```
    SELECT universityId,universityTypeId,universityName FROM 
    University where universityTypeId=:universityTypeId";
```

But I am not getting correct result.Can anyone tell.I am new to SQL.

Comment: You need to use an aggregation function like [count()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT universityTypeId, COUNT(1) 
FROM University where universityTypeId=:universityTypeId
```

OR

```
SELECT universityTypeId, COUNT(1) 
FROM University
GROUP BY universityTypeId
```

OR

```
SELECT universityTypeId, (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM University where universityTypeId = UniversityType.universityTypeId)
     FROM UniversityType
```

Comment: First one will give you count for the type you pass (which is what you were trying?). Second one will give you the count of types that do have a university

Comment: Added third sql which will give you count for all university types

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
SELECT universityId,universityName,count(universityTypeId) as total  FROM 
University group by universityId,universityName
```

You must add all columns list in the group by clause unless it used in the aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
select universityTypeName, COUNT(University.universityId) FROM UniversityType JOIN University  ON UniversityType.universityTypeId = University.universityTypeId GROUP BY UniversityType.universityTypeName
```

Try this query

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables by `UniversityType.universityTypeId` and count the `University`s. So, try this:

```
SELECT t.universityTypeName, count(u.universityId) as total 
FROM University u, UniversityType t 
WHERE u.universityTypeId = t.universityTypeId 
GROUP BY u.universityTypeName;
```

The output it gives is:

```
UGC|2
NCT|1
AICT|1
```